# Display PDF in Android - loaded from external, authenticated URL

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

In my Android app, I need to display a PDF file. The PDF file is read directly from the web, through an API that uses basic authorization (I'm using the Apache HttpClient with a line like `request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBytes(username + ":" + password).getBytes());`)

I've looked through some related questions and the answers seem to either suggest:

- saving the PDF as a file on the SD card then displaying with some other library, like Apache PDFBox (certainly possible, but adds a 9.8MB library to the app and the hassle of file IO).
- displaying the PDF through a WebView by passing the URL through the docs.google.com reader (can't use this approach due to authentication constraint).

I'd be really keen to hear of any possible solutions on this one, thanks!

Comment: You can try using ProGuard to reduce the size of jar lib.